# SVNKit: How to get the revision number from a working directory

Tags: svnkit

I would like to implement a method that can get the svn revision number from the path where a SVN repository has been checked out. The method declaration would look something like this:

```
long getRevisionNumber(String localPath) { ... }
```

I'm trying to use SVNKit for this, but it seems to require an SVN URL to start with. Is there any way to start with a local path?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
public static long getRevisionNumber(String localPath) throws SVNException {
    final SVNStatus status = SVNClientManager.newInstance().getStatusClient().doStatus(new File(localPath), false);
    return status != null ? status.getRevision().getNumber() : -1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Also you can use `getCommittedRevision()` method. It returns revision for a particular file when it was last commited.

```
clientManager.getStatusClient().doStatus(destination, false).getCommittedRevision().getNumber();
```